# refurbishing computers - windows licensing

Tags: windows, license, oem, legal

I thought about refurbishing a couple of computers with Windows 7 or 8. Which license/version would I need to get to be "legal"? Where would I get it? Thanks

edit:
I mustn't have made myself clear. I would get older machine; I would fix them up; I would install a fresh copy of the operating system; I would resell them. I need to know the appropriate license to get. thanks

Comment: You would need to purchase a new license unless it was an OEM machine.  Check with the seller of the machine for more information

Comment: Since you've edited your question to clarify you're planning to do this for resale purposes, I've edited my question to cover that scenario.

Comment: If the old computers have the resources to handle Win 7 well, they probably had Win 7 before, so replacing Win 7 would not be an upgrade.  If they are at all functional, extract the existing license key.  If you are talking about needing a new copy of Windows, that implies that you are doing some major repair/replacement or dealing with severe corruption.  Depending on what you need to replace, you may be able to just download an iso for the same version of windows and use the existing key, or Microsoft may allow you to do it as a repair.

Comment: If the computers are pre-Win 7 vintage, they may lack the resources to run well with Win 7.

Comment: Now if it does have a COA for Windows 7, could I just activate it OEMSLP style with BIOS, Key, Cert, or would I have to use COA key from the sticker? thanks again

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you would need to use the 5x5 key found on the Windows 7 COA present on the machine. BIOS activation is out of the question as no such thing exists for Win 7 (there's BIOS-locking but that *restricts* a key to a certain BIOS). OEM pre-installation is only possible if you're a System Builder and selling a System Builder license, which you would not be.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  If you *are* planning to do this for resale purposes, then you should sign up to become a Microsoft [Registered Refurbisher](http://www.microsoft.com/refurbishedpcs/RRP.aspx).  This program is specifically for those who will repurpose previously used computers, although the program currently offers only Windows 7 licenses, not Windows 8 (as of Dec 2014, this is likely to change in the future).

---

I'm assuming you're doing this for personal use (as opposed for resale purposes).

If your computers have **previously had a Windows license** (making this an "upgrade" scenario), you must buy a **Full Version** license for Windows. These can be purchased from online retailers such as [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com). Search for the terms `Windows 8 Full Version`.

If your computers have **never been previously licensed** for Windows, you can buy a **System Builder** license and take advantage of the [Personal Use License](http://www.geek.com/news/windows-8-gets-personal-use-license-for-anyone-building-their-own-pc-1510469/) Microsoft introduced with Windows 8.  This license type is also available from reputable online retailers. Search for the terms `Windows 8 System Builder`.

Just to clarify, it [isn't legal](http://www.microsoft.com/OEM/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/windows-licensing-for-personal-use.aspx#fbid=KFBmI2KOJWl) use the System Builder license to *upgrade* an existing Windows license. According to the [Windows 8 licensing guide](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/licensing/sblicensing/Pages/index.aspx#fbid=KFBmI2KOJWl):

> The System Builder license for Windows 8 allows for “Do It Yourself”
>   (DIY) customers, for end users who wish to build their own PC for
>   their personal use or install Windows as an additional operating
>   system in a virtual machine or a separate partition. These users are
>   now able to purchase and install the System Builder product.

However if you're upgrading a computer previously licensed with Windows, you're out of luck:

> System Builder product **may not** be used:
>
> - **As an upgrade license to an existing underlying Windows operating system.**
> - To legalize from a non-genuine Windows operating system.
> - To license more than five copies of the software (in total) for commercial use.

Comment: System Builder only exists with Windows 8.  You should clarify the the difference between a retail Windows 7 license, a Windows 7 upgrade license, and Windows 7 oem license.

Comment: Would an OEM license be appropriate?

Comment: @fixer1234 I've updated my answer to explain when/if an OEM/System Builder license would be appropriate.

Comment: @Ramhound Good points. The "System Builder" license of Windows 8 is a continuation of the "OEM" license of Windows 7 and prior, although the terms System Builder and OEM have been [closely associated](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/can-i-buy-an-oem-system-builder-version-of-windows/481871e2-b240-4974-bb98-cb22adf43bc7) for a long time. I didn't cover the various Win 7 licenses because they're no longer sold in Microsoft authorized distribution channels making whatever *is* available at risk of either being illegal copies or ineligible OEM licenses.